# Use applications as video sources for apps like Skype?

Tags: macos, video, quicktime, screen-capture, skype

Is there a solution out there that can screen record 1 application and "stream" it through a fake virtual camera, so the video can be sent live through apps like Skype?

Just wondering if it's possible to, for example, stream a video playing in VLC/QuickTime through Skype, and be able to keep that video going through Skype even when I am doing other things on the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CamTwist](http://camtwiststudio.com) works perfectly for this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [webcamoid](https://github.com/webcamoid/webcamoid), [manycam](https://manycam.com/), and [Magic Camera](http://www.shiningmorning.com/) and the corresponding [VLC plugin](http://vlc2vcam.com/).

Be aware the Magic Camera download seems to be bundled with malware and the VLC plugin is very outdated.

[softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is also a good place to ask.